# How to get the download link of html a tag which has no explicit true link?

Tags: python, html

I encountered a web page that has many download sign like

[image]

If I click on each of these download sign, the browser will start downloading a zip file.

However, it seems that these download sign are just images with no explicit download links can be copied.

I looked into the source of html. I figured out each download sign belong to a tr tag block as below.

```
<tr>
    <td title="aaa">
        <span class="centerFile">
            <img src="/images/downloadCenter/pic.png" />
        </span>aaa
    </td>
    <td>2021-09-10 13:42</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td><a id="4099823" data='{"clazzId":37675171,"libraryId":"98689831","relationId":1280730}' recordid="4099823" target="_blank" class="download_ic checkSafe" style="line-height:54px;"><img src="/images/down.png" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Click this link will download a zip file with download link

[image]

So my problem is how to get download links of these download sign without actually clicking them in the browser. In particular, I want to know how to do this using python by analyzing the source html so I could to do batch downloading?

Comment: When you manually click it. Is there a pattern in the url. for example is it always the same url with only the `id` changed? Then you could just hardcode the url and change the id

Comment: The link download from javascript. You should check js functions.

Comment: @UliSotschok Thank you for reply. See my updated post. It is always the same link.

Comment: @brian_wang Could you give me some guidance？I do not have js knowledge.  I used to extract directly links from source page. But now the web page changed its form.

Comment: @brian_wang Can I just mimic mouse clicking and get the download link using python ?

Comment: Is it possible to post the link of this page here?  Also I think you forgot to save your changes

Comment: @UliSotschok Sorry, I save it now. It is not helpful to post the link, because the link needs login to view

Comment: ok, that wouldn't help.

Comment: To find a pattern in the download links you would need more examples. what I found was at the end: `/pdf/<clazzId>_<relationId>.zip` maybe that helps. You can also (maybe) click on the item in selenium and configure your browser to automatically save the file. You can search the js for parts of this URL and then call this function (js knowledge required)

Comment: yes, you can use python mouse click to download.  Also, you can just find javascript function for download link generation.

Comment: @brian_wang How to use python mouse click?

Comment: @user15964 It is based on your operation system, for windows, you can use pywin32, google it there are a lot of resolutions.

Comment: The information you need in order to create the download link can be found here:

    {"clazzId":37675171,"libraryId":"98689831","relationId":1280730} 

All you have to do is to compose the download URL (see the image you have uploaded) and invoke HTTP call (using `requests`) that will get the file for you.

You can follow the JS code that create the URL and see exactly how to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the batch download of those files, and are not able to find out links by analysis of html and javascript (because it's probably javascript function that creates this link, or javascript call to backend) then you can use selenium to simulate you acting as user.

You will need to do something like code below, where I'm using class name from html you present, where I think is call to javascript download function:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 
# URL of website
url = "https://www.yourwebsitelinkhere.com/"
driver.get(url)

# use class name to find anchor link
download_links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".download_ic.checkSafe")
for link in download_links:
    link.click()
```

Example how it works for stackoverflow (in the day of writing this answer)

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.-marketing-link.js-gps-track')
elements[0].click()
```

And this should lead you to stackoverflow about site.

[EDIT] Answer edited, as it seems compound classes are not supported by selenium, example for stackoverflow added

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me how to do it in selenium! But there is some problem, I can "find_elements_by_id", but "find_elements_by_class_name" gives blank list. Why? Is it a bug in selenium?

Comment: Yeah, seems that now selenium does not support "compound classes". So you should use either css_selector or XPath instead to solve your problem. Check my answer update, I'll put css_selector method there.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I've accepted your answer. But I still have one more question. What if I want just capturing the download link without downloading after clicking? Is there a way to do it in selenium? I did not got a clue after reading the document

Comment: Using selenium will not be enough to get download link, as it only simulates actions on html components. Your actual download links are hidden either by javascript, or even by backend. Of course you can get those links, but you need either to analyze javascript and find where they are created, or to download and analyze network (e.g. in chrome developer tools), then find a pattern ;) . Also you can use Selenium Wire to access the request from Python. If you want to block request - maybe `driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["<blockedURL"]})`.What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking to obtain those download links directly, so I can download and rename the downloaded zip use html information directly via python. I now learned more web technology, and indeed the download links seem to be obtained by javascript ajax, so they can not be directly analyzed by static source page.